# xcode UIbutton setcenter does not move button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I am using `xcode` and am having a problem moving a button automatically.  I have this function that whenever I call it, I expect the button to move to the coordinates that I set:

```
[movebutton setCenter:CGPointMake(164,50)];
```

Previously I tried to set an `NStimer` in an `IBAction` function and then use the timer to call this `movebutton` function - the button moved but if I call the same function without an `NStimer` it no longer works.

The code for the timer is:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.1/3) target:self selector:@selector(movebutton:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Can anyone spot what I am missing?

**Update:**

I try to print out the x and y coordinates of the button and actually the button position has been updated.

```
NSLog(@"x position %f",movebutton.frame.origin.x);
```

however, on the UI screen it *does not reflect at all*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

in your `moveButton:` method so that when it's called from the timer it knows to update the UI.

Comment: hi Bek thanks for the reply. now its working. like what u say i have to update the UI :)

Answer (score 0):

Where do you call -[UIButton setCenter] manually? Couldn't comment because I don't have permission to comment.

The NSTimer works because it fires the method every 0.1/3 because the NSTimer instance is added to run loop

Comment: hi i have created this function "movebutton" and setCenter is inside this method. basically i would like to call this movebutton function and then the button will move according to the coordinates. previously i use a NSTimer and the button moves everytime the method is fired. however, now i do not want to use a timer to control..but without the timer when i call this function the button no longer moves. ideally i would like the button to move whenever i call it..but without any time constraint

Comment: @lkleung1 Where do you call it?